# Flutter Firebase apiKey, appId, messagingSenderId and projectId

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to use `firebase_messaging` to send message from my backend to my flutter apk.

When initialize firebase, these are the 4 keys essential in the `FirebaseOptions`

> **apiKey** : Is this the **Server Key** found in FCM?

> **appId** : Where can I find this key?

> **messagingSenderId** : **Sender ID** FCM

> **projectId** : Where can I find this?

Besides, in order for me to send message to a single user. I need to tell Firebase who am I right? **May I know which ID shall I use?**

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you register with firebase you obtain the push notification token. This token is used to send a notification to the device the app is installed on.

Assuming you already initialized firebase app in flutter, and you added the `google-services.json` in your app. You can obtain your push notification token in the following way:

```dart
messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    messaging.getToken().then((value){
        print(value); //this is the push notification token
});
```

You can also test that you are able to receive the notification on the app from the firebase console. You can send a notification to the app under `Compose notification` section in the firebase console. It only requires the notification token you obtained from the app.

Comment: Will like to add one more thing in sami's answer that whenever user clears data of the app or reinstall app then token expires and new one is provided to the user so take care of it as well.

Comment: @DeepakLohmod can I store the token for future use?

Comment: what do you mean by future use?

Comment: for sure you need to store the token in your db, since you will be notifying the app on this device using this token